# convertir TextInput a mayúsculas con react-native

Tags: react-native

tengo un `onChangeText` que me convierte el texto a mayúsculas en el momento que voy escribiendo, pero al momento que comienzo a borrar algo de lo escrito se comienza a duplicar el texto.

```js
<TextInput
placeholderTextColor="gray" value={name}
onChangeText={(text) => setName(text.toUpperCase())}
selectionColor="orange"
autoCapitalize='none'
autoCorrect={false}
selectTextOnFocus={false}
/>
```